# how to get the left shift value in C?

Tags: c, macros

I have a question the following marco is defined:

```
TO_TI(a, b) ((b)<<13|(a))
```

then I call the following statement:

```
int c = TO_TI(1,2);
```

then I pass the result `c` to a function, in this function, how to based on the value c and input a calculate the value of `b`?

Comment: c = 13; // not sure what you are asking

Comment: Don't use `int`! Macros like these only work safely (reversibly) with `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `a` and `c` you cannot (in general) compute `b`, because a and b were bitwise-OR'd together, and that's not reversible (again, in general).  Consider `a=101` and `b=1` with a shift of 2.  Then `c=101` which is identical to if `b=0`.  There's simple no way to know.

If you were using XOR instead of OR, or you had some more information such as restrictions on the range of the values involved, we might make more progress.

Answer (score 1):

Packing multiple integers into one larger integer is often a useful thing to do, and writing a macro is a good way to get it right (although I'd prefer an inline function, perhaps).

The key thing is that you have to know what you're doing! If you don't understand the underlying bit operations properly, or at least follow the rules, then you won't get back what you put in.

Your TO_TI macro will work fine provided that `a` is a positive integer that uses not more than 12 bits. `b` must not have more that 20 bits of data (assuming 32-bit words).

If `a` is unsigned it can be extracted like this:

```
unsigned int a = c & 0xFFF;
```

But, if `a` is signed then you have to "sign-extend" the value, like this:

```
int a = ((int)c << 20) >> 20;
```

Similarly, if `b` is signed it must be sign-extended, but that's easier:

```
int b = (int)c >> 12;
```

But, is `b` is unsigned you must be very careful *not* to sign-extend it:

```
unsigned int b = (unsigned int)c >> 12;
```

Finally, if you want to allow `a` to have negative values then you macro must be defined like this:

```
#define TO_TI(a, b) ((b)<<13|((a)&0xFFF))
```

(Otherwise the sign-bits of `a` will overwrite `b`.)

If you have three or more values encoded into the same integer then things get even more hairy. And beware of systems where `int` has 64-bits.

The rules:

1. Understand what you want the bits to do.
2. Understand what the bitwise operators do to signed and unsigned values.
3. Test the boundary conditions carefully.

This is why bit-fields were invented and you should strongly consider using them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that a does not have one of bits except the first 12 bits set (then the | would destroy your information on b) you can use & and shift right to reverse the operation:

```
b = (c & ~a) >> 13
```

(The ~a is the bitwise negation of a)

Edit: Indeed is is not even necessary to do the & because by shifting right the lowest 12 bits will be shifted out...

Comment: what if during the left shift operation on b,it causes b to leak out its MSBs? suppose original b has 20th bit as 1 if you `<< 13` on b then you lose this bit.

Comment: Well, thats anoying, but such is life ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The macro `TO_TI` is following an idiom to pack multiple values into bitfields. (It's also winking at you.)

`b << 13` multiplies `b` by 2<sup>13</sup> = 8192. As long as `a` is at most 13 bits long, that is `0 <= a < 8192`, you can recover it by taking the modulus with 8192. You don't need `b` to recover `a`… or vice versa.

The whole idea is that `a` and `b` should be easy to recover from the result of `TO_TI`, so the first thing would be to look at the source around that macro definition to find the macro which is supposed to reverse the process. Otherwise, `c >> 13` should be sufficient to recover `b`.

It should be noted that both numbers must be positive and within the required ranges for this to work. If the author of `TO_TI` never mentioned that `a` cannot be greater than 8192, they were asleep at the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, given *c* resulting from

```
c = b<<13 | a;
```

can we find out the original *a* and *b*?

It depends on

- the length (number of bits) of *a*: besides the problem above, if *a* msb (most significant bit) is 2^13 or more, the `|` operation will impact where *b* is after the shift (`b << 13`), and thus you cannot know if the *c* value from bit 13 is from the original *b*, or from *a*
- the length of *b*: shifting 13 bits is multiplying *b* by 2^13 (8192), and if *b* is originally big enough, after the shift it may overflow *c*, i.e. the result would not fit within *c* size (length), and the *b* retrieved from the method below would be less than the original *b*.

So, **If** *a* is smaller than 8192 (2^13) but positive (otherwise its msb would reach *b* shifted) **and** *b* shifted left 13 bits doesn't overflow *c* you can retrieve *a* and *b*, using

```
a = c & 8191; // 2^13 - 1 or 0x1fff in hexa
b = c >> 13;
```